# Where does the coordinator go in a RxSwift + MVVM + Coordinator situation if coordinators aren't in RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift, coordinator-pattern

I'll keep this as short as possible: we started the app full RxSwift but our coordinators started to get overwhelmed to maintain and extend so we are reworking them to not use RxSwift and now we can't figure out how to use them and where to keep them.

Simplest example: view controller with 1 button, view model, coordinator.
Where do I call `coordinator.navigate(to: .mySection)` and how? Should the coordinator be kept in the view controller? I thought they should be kept in the view model but subscribing in the view model is not the recommended usage.

I don't want to over-engineer this but I hope to get some insightful help.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend going with [XCoordinator](https://github.com/quickbirdstudios/XCoordinator/), and their proposed architecture MVVM-C, I've used in 2 big/complicated apps and it's been a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the coordinator as a dependency of your ViewModels, check out this library: [Action](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/Action).

Action lets you bind the action from a button with the ViewModel. You just define an action in your ViewModel, and bind it in the view. The Action type is just a sequence that admits other sequence as input and returns another sequence as output. So you don't need to use a DisposeBag on your ViewModel.

If you want to see examples, checkout the Action's GitHub project or, if you want to see in app examples, the [Ray Wenderlich RxSwift](https://store.raywenderlich.com/products/rxswift) book has a pretty neat example on how to integrate MVVM and Coordinators.

Answer (score 0):

None of the MVVM elements directly address `Coordinators` so if you are using the benefits of Soroush’s Coordinator pattern, you are probably using VIPER but you may not be aware of this, which is not really important.

In VIPER, the R stands for **Routing** which perfectly fits with the definition of Coordinators.

Two things I really like to suggest are:

1. Most of the turorials on the Internet teach you to create a seperate coordinator for each of your `UIViewController`s  **BUT** I personally asked soroush about this and he replied : it is not the best practice with coordinators. So I used only two coordinators in my latest App and quite happy with the result.
2. If you would like to spend some time on VIPER, I suggest to assume your ViewControllers are the Presentor in your VIPER model; I have seen some VIPER tutorials on the Internet expressing otherwise.

P.S. MVVM is great but it is not scalable, I humbly suggest to take a look at VIPER. Here is [a good article](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/viper/#what-is-viper) that you may find usefull.

Comment: I don't think we're using VIPER since the architecture and the implementation is different; thanks for suggesting it but it's too overwhelming for what we need to do and we found MVVM to be the right fit for now. At the moment we have a coordinator for every section of the app which is made of 3-4 VCs. I guess that, since the context depends on VCs, that's where we should put our coordinators. Thanks!

Comment: @MattiaC. You are free to call it whatever you want, it is a little bit matter of taste. I personally believe, if you use coordinator pattern together with MVVM, you could call it VIPER. Nevertheless, name is not important. Wish you luck. 

Comment: @MattiaC.  The MVVM architecture does not have a **Routing** element, Zich is right, if you have added Coordinators to MVVM then you have a VIPER. Just like when you add ViewModel to MVC you have a MVVM. Sometimes we don’t have to have all parts of an architecture in our app but it doesn’t mean we are not using that architecture.